# Objects being generated, but not being drawn in the correct position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok, so I have a game where I have some tree objects that need to be drawn in one side or another. The problem is, even though the condition is working and the trees are being drawn, they're not following the SIDES_RATE condition, specially on Side 2, they're going to the opposite direction while in Side 1 they're almost moving straight, instead of diagonal.

This is my Tree Class:

```
function Tree1(side, pos_x) {
    this.speed = TREE_SPEED;
    this.side = side;
    this.height = 107;
    this.width = 49.3;
    this.pos_x = pos_x;
    this.pos_y = 10;
    this.tree1_image = tree_images[this.side];
}
```

This is my Tree controller

```
setInterval(generateTree, TREE_SPEED * 1000);

function generateTree() {
    a = (Math.round(Math.random()));
    if (a == 0){
        tree1_array.push(new Tree1(Math.round(Math.random()),200));
    } else {
        tree2_array.push(new Tree2(Math.round(Math.random()),600));
    }
}

function moveTree(tree){
    tree.height += ZOOM_RATE;
    tree.width += ZOOM_RATE;

    if (tree.side == 0){
        tree.pos_x -= SIDES_RATE;
    } else if (tree.side == 1) {
        tree.pos_x += SIDES_RATE;
    }

    tree.pos_y += TREE_SPEED;

}

function treeController(){
    for (i = 0; i < tree1_array.length; i++){
        if (tree1_array[i].pos_y > 900){
            tree1_array.splice(i,1);
        } else {
            moveTree(tree1_array[i]);
        }

    }
```

}

This is where I draw them:

```
Game.draw = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < tree1_array.length; i++) {
        this.context.drawImage(tree1_array[i].tree1_image,
            tree1_array[i].pos_x - tree1_array[i].width/2,
            tree1_array[i].pos_y - tree1_array[i].height/2,
            tree1_array[i].width,
            tree1_array[i].height);
    }
}
```

I don't know what's happening for it to happen. Anything helps.

Comment: Your random function that decides which side the tree belongs on seems correct. You may need to post more code, because I can see the you select the tree image to use here: this.tree1_image = tree_images[this.side]; Reading your code, I can't be sure what is in the tree_images array. Maybe try changing the "this.side" variable in the tree_images array to [0] or [1] and see if the trees show up?

Comment: @MatthewKiefer I updated my question. Some things changes, they're being drawn after all, but not at SIDES_RATE.

Comment: Is tree1_array being treated any differently than tree2_array? From your code, I don't see the reason for the extra complexity of maintaining two arrays.